# Capture a string from JSON response

Tags: bash, grep, sed, cut-command

I have below Json response for POST method in bash and would like to capture value after **sessionId":"** and assign it to variable **session_ID**.

{"changeId":"79911476-53a4-46e1-8ffd-422436b51ad1","changeType":"created","record":{"key":"159.65.198.219"}},{"changeId":"bd52dcbd-a5ab-4557-b2b8-88793c2d2964","changeType":"created","record":{"key":"161.35.111.167"}},{"changeId":"f4f5c94e-6c06-473c-b810-b7bbd69c71ad","changeType":"created","record":{"key":"161.35.123.111"}}],**"sessionId":"b7305d77-20f1-4d57-9eb1-9b9fb4f9552d"**}

#API call

request_post="$(curl --insecure --request POST "endpoint_URL")"

echo $request_post

**I need help to complete below step**

#Cut out sessionId from response

**session_ID=**

Comment: You should use the `jq` command. Google "How use jq command in Linux"

Comment: If you want help with `jq`, please make sure that your example is a complete parsable JSON fragment

Answer (score 0):

While parsing json structures should be done by a json parser, trivial cases like this can be done with a trivial tool and you may pipe the answer though `sed`, for example:

```
sed 's/.*"sessionId":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/'
      \______________/  \___/  \/
             A            B    C
```

A matches everything upto and including `"sessionId":"`, B matches all following non-`"`, which is the actual sessionId, and C matches the rest of the line. B is included in `\(\)`, so it can be referred to in the replacement as `\1`. So the whole line is replaced by the sessionId only.

Of course, if the output can be split over several lines or uses other variations allowed by json format, the script will get more complicated.